# Clean up output added via wp_head()

Tags: post-meta, seo, headers, functions

I know that `wp_head()` is important, but using it injects so much crap into the header. I'd like to get it out and just add manually the 2-3 line of code that I need.

But, there is certain code added by WordPress that I want to keep:

```
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<link rel='canonical' href='http://jlecologia.com/cms/' />
...
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="fr-FR" />
```

How can this be generated for me? (Something like `bloginfo('name')` will be fine for me.)

Comment: andre You might get more targeted answers if you explain what's in the header that you *don't* want and what's missing that you *do* want.  Right now it sounds like all you want are the `<meta>` and `<link>` elements above ... which is why @Wyck suggested the code to remove everything else.

Comment: You also might get better answers if you didn't come off as being so angry and if you revised your title to something that didn't show your general ignorance of the utility you're lambasting.

Comment: I follow your GREAT advices, and tremendous wisdom by including it, and removing stuff i dont need with remove_action... I will be less an asshole next time choosing wording more carefully, who live, learn !, thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove some of the header stuff with the following.

```
// remove unncessary header info
function remove_header_info() {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'index_rel_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link');
}
add_action('init', 'remove_header_info');
```

The default installation does not include stuff like meta keywords, so that is either a theme or plugin that you are using.

Comment: not my question, but will check it out...

Comment: @marc This is an incomplete answer to your question. The real answer is: don't remove `wp_head()`. Wyck's suggestion will stop wp_head from inserting what you don't want without ruining your site's compatibility with virtually every javascript-based plugin in the repository.

Comment: adding the action to `init` did not work for me; `after_setup_theme` works. (functions.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

Essentially you need to add an action for the `wp_head` hook, and (probably) remove the other actions that have been associated with the wp_head hook.